# Configuring OpenVPN

Tags: vpn, openvpn

i have installed openvpn using this command.

`sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn`

but the openvpn option in VPN Connections>Configure VPN> still doesn't show up. How to setup an OpenVpn (e.g [VpnBook](http://vpnbook.com)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to also install gnome extension, 
 (with `sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn-gnome`) if you want graphical interface integration with network manager.

Comment: Thanks. this worked but internet is not working chrome gives 'DNS_BAD_CONFIG' error.

Comment: I think that belongs to openvpn config you are using (both server and client), maybe you could post another question and people can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I use this on numerous distro's . I know it works on Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04.

Use your choice of editor, if your new, and if you do not know what that means open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> copy the code, below and paste it into your terminal then, make the appropraite edit. Finish with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> then confirm save location with return, and exit the editor with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>

```
sudo nano /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf
```

Uncomment 'prepend domain-name-servers'then add 3 dns server IP's in the region your going to use from vpnbook -example I live in United States, I use the Germany configuration bundle, so I want my nameservers to be located in Germany, or close. Mine looks like this

'prepend domain-name-servers 87.234.59.172, 130.255.73.90, 8.8.8.8;'

now restart your network

```
$ sudo service network-manager restart
```

open your browser I use firefox and type:

'about:config'

in the search box type

'media.peerconnection.enabled'

right-click then choose toggle. It needs to be not enabled.

navigate to https://www.vpnbook.com

choose 'free vpn' tab and pick your region you want. As I mentioned earlier I chose Germany or 'DE' once it downloads, close the browser, open a terminal:

```
$ cd ~/Downloads
$ unzip VPNBook.com-OpenVPN-DE1.zip 
$ sudo openvpn vpnbook-de233-udp25000.ovpn
```

enter the username and password from the same tab you downloaded the vpn bundle from when, your prompted to do so

If your network prevents udp connections then use one of the TCP files instead they are all the same with different config settings for connection type.

WAIT a good minute or two before opening your browser. Wait until you see "Initialization Sequence Completed"

Open browser and navigate to https://www.dnsleaktest.com/ you should see something like:
[image]

Also test your IP address at whats my IP at ip-adress.eu

[image]

Go through the tests at https://malwaretips.com/threads/the-ultimate-online-privacy-test-resource-list.54694/. And be sure to investigate how to mitigate vulnerabilities, and educate yourselves. Follow browsing best practices for using VPNs effectively, and use common sense. Do not use the VPN to log into your ISP provided email account, recover lost passwords, or stuff like that.

The configurations are basic, but this answer's the question.

This will get you on a free, premium grade vpn using IPv4, deal with some basic DNS problems, and blocks web sites ability to see host IP using a VPN, by disabling the WebRTC protocol.

If you use a bundle from someplace else, simply Google "open free dns servers [your desired region]," but do a little research to ensure the dns is legit, see what users say in forums, and avoid using one because it was the first one to list.

I have some unresolved issues with IPv6, I am still working on. When these issues are resolved I will edit the post.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to [edit] your post to include the version of Ubuntu you accomplished this with? Thank you.

Comment: Made the edit. Note: I use the xfce desktop on Ubuntu 16.04, but this procedure is from a lab in college. I changed nothing except the DNS servers, and we set it up in Kali 2016.1, but as I it works in Ubuntu as well.