# VPN works on colleagues' MacOS (via Tunnelblick) but not on Ubuntu 20.04 (Openvpn)

Tags: network-manager, vpn, openvpn, bind

The company I work for has a vpn. I have been given an .ovpn and .crt file and the setup goes smoothly. But when I try to log in I get the following entries in syslog:

```
nm-openvpn[11198]: UDP link local: (not bound)
nm-openvpn[11198]: [server] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]0.000.00.000:1194
nm-openvpn[11198]: AUTH: Received control message: AUTH_FAILED
nm-openvpn[11198]: SIGUSR1[soft,auth-failure] received, process restarting
```

The VPN works for my colleagues when they use Tunnelblick on MacOs but I'm the only one using Ubuntu here!

How can I fix this? I have the impression I had fixed this on a previous install by installing bind9 and modifying named.conf.options but the person who had helped me do that no longer works here.

(I have more logs I can provide.)

Comment: Are you using the terminal to connect to the VPN server or the Network Manager app? If the former, try using the app. See [this answer for details on instaljation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/817444/configuring-openvpn). You may also find this ["how to"](https://kifarunix.com/connect-to-openvpn-using-network-manager-on-centos-8-ubuntu-18-04/) useful.

Comment: @user68186 I'm using the VPN option in the settings/Network. I have the impression that's OpenVpn, right?

Comment: I suggest that you contact your employer for the settings needed to connect to their VPN.